# Change the root directory of Go project to not be src

Tags: go

Ahoy,

We have a large monolithic repository with all our code in it.  We have recently started to use Go, however, are having issues since most tooling for Go assumes that the root directory is src/ but ours is not. Our directory structure is based on product areas and not based on language or tooling.  We don't want to have a separate directory just for Go.

How can we setup the Go path to not assume that the directory starts at src?

Thanks!

Comment: If you want to use the standard Go tools, then you need to use GOPATH. The tools work by following convention, so you need to folllow that too.

Comment: You can simply create symlinks but then you might have some issues when using [dep](https://github.com/golang/dep) as dependency manager.

[Here](https://github.com/golang/dep/issues/1146) is one example of issue you may encounter

Comment: The statement "Go assumes that the root directory is src/" is incorrect. Instead the `go` tools assume the Go code they operate is organized in one or more *workspaces* — each of which has a certain simple structure: contains the three directories named "src", "pkg" and "bin" at its top level. Please read [this](https://golang.org/doc/code.html#Organization) to gain full understanding of the concept.

Comment: To add to Vardius comment. Perhaps go the over way round don't fight `go` leave everything physically under `GOPATH` and let symlink in your product structure point into the `GOPATH\src\PojectX`. Could be a lot of manual symlinking but you keep `go` happy. This helps to keep everything (`go`, `js`, etc etc) under one Project hierarchy.

Answer (score 1):

The safest course of action is to have two worktrees:

- one for your current directory structure, based on product areas
- one for Go development respecting GOPATH

Each time you will make a commit in the second worktree, you can git pull/update your first worktree to keep it up-to-date.

Comment: @elfsЯus, see [this](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree) for more info. Another approach is to use the [`gb` tool](https://getgb.io/about/) which replaces (or wraps) most of `go` to allow "project-based" approach to working with the Go code. (I'd note that while the `gb` tool is written and maintained to a well-visible and respected Go hacker, I, for one, would try hard to stick to the stock tools if possible.)